# find all elements and if don't have the class, add other class use jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var $trs = $("#task-list-tbody").find("tr");

$.each($trs, function(index, item){
  if(!item.hasClass("tGroup")){
    item.addClass("subgroup");
  }
});
```

this is failed,how can I do?
  I just want to add subgroup class if the tr elements has no tGroup class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A shorter version

```
$("#task-list-tbody").find("tr:not(.tGroup)").addClass('subgroup');
```

Comment: Very nice, `1 line === 6 lines` :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is suffering

> Object #`<HTMLTableRowElement>` has no method 'hasClass'

So *enclose `item` with `$()`* because when you iterate the `trs`, *it will returns individual items a html `<tr>..</tr>`.*

Finally,

```
$.each($trs, function(index, item){
  if(!$(item).hasClass("tGroup")){
        $(item).addClass("subgroup");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $trs = $("#task-list-tbody").find("tr");

$trs.each(function(){
   if($(this).attr('class').indexOf('tGroup') == -1){
      $(this).addClass('subgroup');
   }
});
```